# Como ordenar array de json, por fecha DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: javascript, json, date, ecmascript-6

necesito devolver un array de json que se ordene por fecha forma descendente, el formato en el que recibo las fechas es en DD/MM/YYYY.

Actualmente estaba utilizando esta sentencia, pero no logro que me las ordene

```
data.activities.sort((a, b) => {
                    new Date(a.acti_assign) > new Date(b.acti_assign)
                });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

prueba con:

```
data.activities.sort((a, b) => {
  const as = a.acti_assign.split("/");
  const ad = new Date(as[2], as[1] - 1, as[0]);
  const bs = b.acti_assign.split("/");
  const bd = new Date(bs[2], bs[1] - 1, bs[0]);      
  return ad - bd;
});
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos